# Email technology that allows users to respond by clicking yes or no or other actions

Tags: email

Is there any email technology that allows users to respond by clicking yes or no or other actions?

Must preferably work with Microsoft Outlook and Novell Groupwise.

So basically a manager would get an email for say an approval of an employee's bonus. The manager can then just click Approve or Decline; and a return email will be sent with action that the manager clicked on.

Comment: Hmm.. Why one should need managers then? Let's write a script, it will respond to the messages randomly clicking "Yes" or "No":)

Comment: Outlook has a '[voting](https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/add-voting-buttons-to-a-message-HP005242171.aspx)' response built in...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the email body you can send two links:

Something like this:

```
example.com/question?verificationCode=...&answer=yes

example.com/question?verificationCode=...&answer=no
```

There can be two images linked to these links.

This would be the method I am thinking.